# Paired data in a lmer with repeated measures in R?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, paired-data

I have a dataset consisting of a measured variable (**height**) repeated over many days for multiple individuals (**id**) and at 3 different **times** per day (Morning, Day, Night).

I want to know if the height is different for the time of day measured.

Here is subset of my data:

```
id          time            height      pair
1           Day             37          1
1           Night           115         1
1           Morning         39          1
1           Day             73          2
1           Night           80          2
1           Morning         24          2
2           Day             88          3
2           Night           63          3
2           Morning         25          3
2           Day             24          4
2           Night           58          4
2           Morning         92          4
3           Day             59          5
3           Night           91          5
3           Morning         77          5
3           Day             82          6
3           Night           69          6
3           Morning         112         6
```

Using lmer in R:
**id** (factor) is considered as repeated measure (and included as a random effect)
**height** and **time** (factor) are fixed effects.

```
lmer(height ~ time+(1|id), data=data, REML=F)
```

But I feel this is missing out on important structure in the data, because the heights are not independent of one another. I specifically would like to test if the height of the morning is different to the height of the previous night, and if the height of the previous day is different to the following night.

I can do a wilcox.test for paired data, but then I cannot account for the repeated measures (for the **id**).

```
wilcox.test(height ~ group, data = data, paired = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to test these paired data in the lmer model?
One solution I tried was to encode these paired observations as a factor called **pair** and adding it as a fixed effect to the lmer model (and using AIC model comparisons with a null model).

```
m1<-   lmer(height ~ time+pair+(1|id), data=data, REML=F)
null<- lmer(height ~ pair+(1|id), data=data, REML=F)
```

However, I am not certain if this is the correct model to test my hypothesis.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!